# A part of AJAX response storing in PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I need to store a piece of data, into PHP variable, which is received through AJAX response in an input box. How can I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#user_id").change(function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      var dataString = 'user_id='+ id;

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "wmat_details.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
          var data = result.split(",");

          $('#name').val(data[0]);
          $('#email').val(data[1]);
          $('#ref_id').val(data[2]);
          $('#candidature_start').val(data[3]);
          $('#candidature_end').val(data[4]);
          $('#default_attempts').val(data[5]);
          $('#existing_complimentary').val(data[6]);
          $('#wmat_start').val(data[9]);
          $('#wmat_end').val(data[10]);
          $('#attempts_taken').val(data[11]);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

As shown in above code, I want to store `$('#attempts_taken').val(data[11]);` this value to a PHP variable. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: either you need to do operation with your `data[11]` before giving the response. or need to make another ajax call with that data. You cannot store javacript ajax response into a php variable.

Comment: Well, you can instead put it in a session inside `wmat_details.php`, or do the other business there too. You can't really pass it to a `php` variable after the `ajax` has been finished

Comment: I think it is not possible, after page loads you cannot change the server side php variables. What you can do here is to apply some js tricks to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Why you want to store in php  variable? Please mention in your question

Comment: @CarlBinalla Thanks alot. SESSION variable did the work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't.

PHP is server side while jQuery (JS) is client side. They are two separate layers of abstraction that interact only when the client call the server.

I don't have enough informations about what you need to do with data[11] but it seems that you have only one option: make a consecutive AJAX call to the php file that will manipulate data[11].

The consecutive AJAX call must be executed from inside the first call success callback; something like this:

```
success: function(result){
     // Your on success logic
     // ...
     // Prepare the object to send to the server
     var objData = {};
     objData.attemptsTaken = data[11];
     // Execute the second AJAX call to the server
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "second_call_destination_file.php",
         data: objData,
         success: function(result){
             // Do something on success
         },
         error: function(){
             // Do something on error
         },
         complete: function(){
             // Do something on complete (executed after success and error)
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store ajax response into a php variable.

**way 1 :**

You can make another ajax call.

**way 2 :**

you can set session.